# Unable to save one to many relationship entities at the same time on same JSP page using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jsp

I'm new to Spring and trying to build a sample application. In this I have a Company(OwnerCompany) which can have multiple locations(OwnerCompanyOffices). I am trying to save the company and it multiple locations at the same time using same JSP page.I'm not able to get proper data from my JSP page to the spring controller. My Hibernate logs are like this

```
OwnerCompanyOffices [id=0, name=null, location=null, ownerCompany=null]
Hibernate: insert into owner_company_offices (location, name, owner_company_id) values (?, ?, ?)
```

Here is my code
My OwnerCompany Entity **OwnerCompany.java**

```
package com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.entity;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "owner_company")
public class OwnerCompany {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "short_name")
    private String short_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner_company",cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Users>  users;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "ownerCompany", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<OwnerCompanyOffices> ownerCompanyOffices;

    public OwnerCompany() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public OwnerCompany(String name, String short_name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.short_name = short_name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getShort_name() {
        return short_name;
    }

    public void setShort_name(String short_name) {
        this.short_name = short_name;
    }

    public Set<Users> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(Set<Users> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<OwnerCompanyOffices> getOwnerCompanyOffices() {
        return ownerCompanyOffices;
    }

    public void setOwnerCompanyOffices(List<OwnerCompanyOffices> ownerCompanyOffices) {
        this.ownerCompanyOffices = ownerCompanyOffices;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OwnerCompany [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", short_name=" + short_name + ", users=" + users
                + ", ownerCompanyOffices=" + ownerCompanyOffices + "]";
    }

    public void addOwnerCompanyOffices(OwnerCompanyOffices ownerCompanyOffice) {
        if(ownerCompanyOffices == null) {
            ownerCompanyOffices = new ArrayList<OwnerCompanyOffices>();
        }

        ownerCompanyOffices.add(ownerCompanyOffice);
        ownerCompanyOffice.setOwnerCompany(this);
    }
}
```

My OwnerCompanyOffices Entity **OwnerCompanyOffices.java**

```
package com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="owner_company_offices")
public class OwnerCompanyOffices {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="location")
    private String location;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "owner_company_id")
    private OwnerCompany ownerCompany;

    public OwnerCompanyOffices() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public OwnerCompanyOffices(String name, String location) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public OwnerCompany getOwnerCompany() {
        return ownerCompany;
    }

    public void setOwnerCompany(OwnerCompany ownerCompany) {
        this.ownerCompany = ownerCompany;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OwnerCompanyOffices [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", location=" + location + ", ownerCompany="
                + ownerCompany + "]";
    }
}
```

My OwnerCompanyOfficesDAO class **OwnerCompanyOfficesDAOImp**

```
package com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.dao;

import java.util.List;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.entity.OwnerCompanyOffices;

@Repository
public class OwnerCompanyOfficesDAOImp implements OwnerCompanyOfficesDAO {

    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public List<OwnerCompanyOffices> getAllOffices() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveOffice(OwnerCompanyOffices ownerCompanyOffice) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.saveOrUpdate(ownerCompanyOffice);

    }

}
```

My OwnerCompanyController Class **OwnerCompanyController**

```
package com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.dao.OwnerCompanyDAO;
import com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.dao.OwnerCompanyOfficesDAO;
import com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.entity.OwnerCompany;
import com.sachinmukherjee.spring_hibernate.entity.OwnerCompanyOffices;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/owner_company/")
public class OwnerCompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private OwnerCompanyDAO ownerCompanyDAO;

    @Autowired
    private OwnerCompanyOfficesDAO ownerCompanyOfficesDAO;

    @GetMapping("/add/")
    public String add(Model model) {
        OwnerCompanyOffices ownerCompanyOffices = new OwnerCompanyOffices();
        model.addAttribute("ownerCompanyOffices", ownerCompanyOffices);
        return "owner_company/add";
    }

    @PostMapping("/submit")
    public String submit(@ModelAttribute("ownerCompanyOffices") OwnerCompanyOffices ownerCompanyOffices) {
        System.out.println(ownerCompanyOffices);
        ownerCompanyOfficesDAO.saveOffice(ownerCompanyOffices);
        return "redirect:/owner_company/";
    }
}
```

My add.jsp page where I'm entering the ownercompany and ownercompanyoffices data

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
        <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/owner_company/submit/" method="POST" modelAttribute="ownerCompanyOffices" class="form-control">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input name="ownerCompanyOffices.ownerCompany.name" required="required"/>
            </br></br>
            <label>Short Name</label>
            <input name="ownerCompanyOffices.ownerCompany.short_name" type="text" />
            </br></br>
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="toClone">
                    <td><input type="text" name="ownerCompanyOffices.name" required="required"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="ownerCompanyOffices.location" required="required"/></td>
                    <td class="remove"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr id="addRow">
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="addMore">Add More</a>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </form>
      </div>

     </div>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on("click",".addMore", function(){
        var clonedRow = $(".toClone:first").clone();
        $(clonedRow).find("input").each(function(){
            $(this).val("");
        });
        $(clonedRow).addClass("toRemove");
        $(clonedRow).find(".remove").addClass("removeRow");
        $(clonedRow).find(".remove").html("<a href='#'>Remove</a>");
        $(clonedRow).insertBefore($("#addRow"));

});

$(document).on("click",".removeRow", function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
});
</script>
```

[image: Screenshot]
Here By clicking on add more link user can add multiple offices against a single company.

Comment: This question is somewhat misleading. You make is seem like it's a spring/hibernate problem when the main and possibly only problem is that you are not getting the data correctly transferred from the frontend to the backend.

Comment: @InsertKnowledge Sorry for that. I'm editing the question so that it doesn't mislead any one